# Стандарт кодирования математических выражений

Tags: математика, стандарт

Есть необходимость в сохранении и передаче математических выражений, причем в перспективе хранение этих самых выражений должно происходить неограниченное время. Я предположил формат LaTeX и в конечном результате получилось что-то вроде:

```
{"task":"lim_{n\rightarrowinfty}\frac{n-1}{3n};","solution":"lim_{n\rightarrowinfty}\frac{n-1}{3n}=lim_{n\rightarrowinfty}\frac{\frac{n}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{3n}{n}}=lim_{n\rightarrowinfty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{3}=\frac{1}{3};","answer":"\frac{1}{3};"}
```

Но меня стали одолевать сомнения в правильности выбора формата: я не имею представления, насколько он универсален и стандартизирован, знаю только о его популярности в web. Может быть, дадите почитать что-нибудь об этом? Или не существует стандарта цифрового хранения математических записей?

Основные требования заключаются в минимальности исходника и возможности его однозначной интерпретации. Уже даже подумывал разработать свой стандарт (ох уж эта эфемерность мысли программиста).

Comment: Лате*х* отличный формат для формул. Еще существует MathML, но он сильно громоздкий, так как базируется на xml.

Comment: Я это знаю, но хочется услышать это еще от кого-то для уверенности. Так что спасибо)

Comment: +1 за LaTeX, это де факто стандарт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько стандартов записи математических формул. Из них выделю следующие, для реализации рекомендую именно в таком порядке:

- LaTeX - de facto стандарт для набора математических (и не только формул) уже многие годы; из плюсов - очень широкая поддержка во всех популярных математических продуктов (даже в sympy для Python'а есть экспорт в LaTeX), читаемый формат, весьма простой и однозначный для парсинга.
- MathML - стандарт для набора формул на базе XML, весьма специфичен, не читаем, поддерживается весьма слабо.
- [eqn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eqn) - популярный в узких кругах способ записи.
- MathType - устаревший стандарт из Office 2007 и ранее, сейчас практически нигде не поддерживается и крайне малопопулярен и даже в официальной реализации весьма медленный.

Есть ещё множество стандартов: [OMML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/omml-specification-version-2), [OpenMath](https://www.openmath.org/), [OMDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMDoc) и другие, более узкоспециализированные.

Answer (score 0):

[Reverse Polish Notation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) - невозможно придумать что-то более универсальное, стандартизированное (единственный спецсимвол - пробел), минималистичное и однозначное.

Comment: И что в нем стандартизированного? Где написано, как записать интеграл в обратной польской записи? Какие есть библиотеки, чтобы отрендерить уравнение Эйлера из ОПН в картинку?

Comment: Почитал, не увидел интегрирования.

Comment: > И что в нем стандартизированного?

Все. Абсолютно все. Единственное, что там можно стандартизировать - разделитель. Он стандартизирован - это пробел.

> Где написано, как записать интеграл в обратной польской записи?

Фейспалм. Прочтите еще раз статью из Википедии, Вы в ней ничего не поняли, судя по всему. В том-то и прелесть, что все всегда записывается одним способом - конкатенативным. https://clck.ru/9SqmE

> Какие есть библиотеки, чтобы отрендерить уравнение Эйлера из ОПН в картинку?

Понятия не имею. Человек вроде бы хотел даже свой стандарт придумать. Вот я и дал идею такого стандарта